# IntelliJ create Web App

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea, glassfish

I want to create with Java Spring, Hibernate and Glassfish an Web App. 
But, I already have problems to generate an Website. IntelliJ says that the artifact is employed successful.

At the moment I have:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
  @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printWelcome(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("message","hello world");
    return "hallo";
  }
}
```

I didn´t changed anything in the `web.xml` or in the `index.jsp`, they are the generated ones from IntelliJ.

In Glassfish I have

```
http://localhost:8080/dgj:war_exploded/index.form
and domain1
```

In the Project Structure were some problems, but IntelliJ fixed it.

When I run it I get an 404 and the mime is not jsp, but form - which is the specified one in .
The log File shows no Errors but the Warning:

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1432336020566] [levelValue: 900] [[
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dgj:war_exploded/index.form]     in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher']]
```

Comment: Why you don't use the spring tool suite with spring boot? The big benefit of spring boot is the Java configuration, that means you don't need any xml configuration

Comment: Well, I am just starting with Spring. Never heard of the suite. But since it´s for Eclipse... Is it any good? I like IntelliJ way more than Eclipse. And at the moment I have no clue of this Boot/MVC stuff etc. I am currently reading about Incection , IOC and AOP, but if you have an good Introduction about Spring Boot you can tell me.

Comment: i like intellij too but for developing with spring the spring tool suite is perfect. I have learning spring boot step by step with the following: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ it's very clear and quick to learn. I Wish You Success

Comment: Actually current Intellij IDEA 14.1 has a strong support of Spribg boot. You can check this webinar http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/04/webinar-recording-spring-boot-and-intellij-idea-14-1/. It's a bit advanced and assumes that you are familiar with spring, but anyway it gives an overview of their frameworks and IDEA support. And here https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications you can learn how to deploy spring boot applicaiton to existing server.